# In Lucene How to Index the word position of text file

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, zend-search-lucene

I am new in lucene environment and using  [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lucene/lucene_first_application.htm).

1-  Indexer.java class is used to index the raw data so that we can make it searchable using lucene library.

2-  LuceneConstants.java class is used to provide various constants to be used across the sample application.

3-  Searcher.java class is used to search the indexes created by Indexer to search the requested contents.

4-  TextFileFilter.java class is used as a .txt file filter.

5-  LuceneTester.java lass is used to test the indexing and search capability of       lucene library..

Now I am trying to index the Field for word position(TermVectorPosition) in Indexer.java and retrieve it through query in LuceneTester.java .  Any one help me

Comment: By default it indexes the position.  Search on implementing a custom highlights and it should lead you to word position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public void doSearch(String querystr) throws IOException, ParseException {      


   StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);  

   Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));  

   // 2. query  

   Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, LuceneConstants.Term_Vector_Position, analyzer).parse(querystr);  


   // 3. search  
   int hitsPerPage = 10;  
   IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);  
   IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index, true);  
   searcher.setDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, true);  
   TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);  
   searcher.search(q, collector);  
   ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;  

   // 4. display term positions, and term indexes   
   System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");  
 //  System.out.println("Found " + hits.clone().length+ " hits.");
   for(int i=0;i<hits.clone().length;++i) {  

       int docId = hits[i].doc;  
       System.out.println("docId:" + docId);
       TermFreqVector tfvector = reader.getTermFreqVector(docId, "TVP");  
       TermPositionVector tpvector = (TermPositionVector)tfvector; 
       System.out.println("tfvector " + tfvector + " tpvector" + tpvector);
       int termidx = tfvector.indexOf(querystr);  
       System.out.println("termidx " + termidx );
       int[] termposx = tpvector.getTermPositions(termidx);
       //System.out.println("termposx " + termposx.length);
       TermVectorOffsetInfo[] tvoffsetinfo = tpvector.getOffsets(termidx);

     for (int j=0;j<termposx.length;j++) {  
          System.out.println("termpos at j :"+j + ": " +termposx[j]);  
      } 

      System.out.println("tvoffsetinfo " + tvoffsetinfo.length);

      for (int j=0;j<tvoffsetinfo.length;j++) {  
          int offsetStart = tvoffsetinfo[j].getStartOffset();  
          int offsetEnd = tvoffsetinfo[j].getEndOffset();  
          System.out.println("offsets : "+offsetStart+" "+offsetEnd);  
      }  

      Document d = searcher.doc(docId);  
      System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("filepath"));

   }

    // searcher can only be closed when there  
   // is no need to access the do***ents any more.   
   searcher.close();
```

}